# Angular - ng-template with parameter inside ngIf inside ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-template, ng-template

I am trying to build this template:

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor='let link of links'>
        <ng-container *ngIf="link.type == 'complex'; then complexLink else simpleLink"></ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #simpleLink>
    ...
    {{ link.some_property }}
</ng-template>

<ng-template #complexLink>
    ...
    {{ link.some_property }}
</ng-template>
```

The problem is that the link variable is undefined inside the ng-template so I get an error of accessing 'some_property' of undefined.

I am struggeling to understand how I pass the link variable from the ngFor to the ng-template

It would be great to know if there are multiple solutions for this problem.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

You can do it like :

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor='let link of links'>
        <ng-container 
             [ngTemplateOutlet]="link.type == 'complex' ?complexLink : simpleLink" 
             [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{link:link}">
        </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #simpleLink let-link='link'>
    Simple : {{ link.name }}
</ng-template>

<ng-template #complexLink let-link='link'>
    Complex : {{ link.name }}
</ng-template>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-container-conditional2)**

Comment: Hi Vivek i need to pass external values like output to  access [ngTemplateOutletContext]  in another component  refer this plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/lHFWI9KEHXPaJT4YKDkD?p=preview

Comment: Your answer helped me grasp the concept that each `ng-template` has its own context of template variables. Ended up helping me build a great page. Thanks!

Comment: Updated syntax: `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="simpleLink; context: {link: link}"></ng-container>` https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Comment: Hey Vivek, is it possible to pass multiple values at once? Thanks for the example though.

Comment: Yes you can pass json to `ngTemplateOutletContext`,as shown above each key considered as variable

Answer (score -20):

You can use it in this way

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let link of links'>
      <ng-container *ngIf="link.type == 'complex'; then complexLink else simpleLink"></ng-container>

      <ng-template #simpleLink>
          ... {{ link.some_property }}
      </ng-template>

      <ng-template #complexLink>
          ... {{ link.some_property }}
      </ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to define the template variable 'link' like so: `<ng-template #simpleLink let-link='link'>`