# if else inside of the ngFor loop in Angular 8+

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I wonder if there's an option for putting `if else` statement inside of the for loop.

I have example here if there's an any chance of converting this PHP code to angular.

**PHP EXAMPLE**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
   $section = $row['name'];

   if($section_id == "TEST_ID") {
      $section = "APPROVED";
   }
   else {
      $section = "DECLINED";
   }

   echo $section;

}
```

**ANGULAR CODE**

**NOTE:** This is a example code only for the reference.

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
    <td>{{ student.student_id | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.section }}</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" (click)="edit(student)">EDIT</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-block" (click)="delete(student)">DELETE</button</td>
</tr>
```

I do research about this problem but I'm so confused since I'm a beginner in this framework. Please help me out of this problem, thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking for **ngIf**

Comment: The `*ngIf` directive is needed in Angular for this:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Comment: Yes Sir Sameer, but I wonder why how can I put it in the code. Please help :((

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply filters to \*ngFor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34164413/how-to-apply-filters-to-ngfor)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \*ngIf else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43006550/how-to-use-ngif-else)

Comment: Where do u want to use ngIf in tr or in td ?

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort, Can you check this stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-qts57i which handles else block..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do with directives

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
    <td>{{ student.student_id | uppercase }}</td>
    <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
    <td *ngIf="student.sectionId == TestID">APPROVED</td>
    <td *ngIf="student.sectionId != TestID">DECLINED</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" (click)="edit(student)">EDIT</button></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-block" (click)="delete(student)">DELETE</button</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, but I wonder why how can I put the else statement since this example is for if statement only. Thank you

Comment: I don't consider this as acceptable answer because the ngIf statement is tested twice in every iteration and this can be costly in some situation

Comment: the acceptbale answer might be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515267/angular-ng-template-with-parameter-inside-ngif-inside-ngfor

Answer (score 0):

use NgTemplateOutlet and ngTemplateOutletContext

```
<tr *ngFor="let student of students">
<td>{{ student.student_id | uppercase }}</td>
<td>{{ student.name }}</td>
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="student.sectionId == TestID  ? approved: 
             declined" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{student:student}">
</ng-container>
<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" (click)="edit(student)">EDIT</button></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger btn-block" (click)="delete(student)">DELETE</button</td>
        </tr>
<ng-template #approved let-s="student">
<td>APPROVED</td>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #declined let-s="student">
<td>DECLINED</td>
</ng-template>
```